# Defining a list of values for a dictionary key using an external file

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a file with a list of paired entries (keys) that goes like this:

```
6416    2318
84665   88
90  2339
2624    5371
6118    6774
```

And I've got another file with the values to those keys:

```
266743  Q8IUM7
64343   H7BXU6
64343   Q9H6S1
64343   C9JB40
23301   Q8NDI1
23301   A8K930
```

As you can see the same key can have more than one value. What I'm trying to do is creating a dictionary by automatically creating the initial k, v pair, and then append more values for each entry that is already in the dictionary, like this:

Program finds `"266743: 'Q8IUM7'"`, then `"64343: 'H7BXU6'"`. And when it finds `"64343: 'Q9H6S1'"` it does this: `"64343: ['H7BXU6', 'Q9H6S1']"`.

This is what I have so far:

```
# Create dictionary
    data = {}

    for line in inmap:
        value = []
        k, v = [x.strip() for x in line.split('\t')]
        data[k] = value.append(v)
        if k in data.viewkeys() == True and v in data.viewvalues() == False:
            data[k] = value.append(v)
```

But the if statement seems to not be working. That or having the `value = []` inside the for loop. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a good idea. You should be using a list from the start and expand that list as you go along, not change from "string" to "list of strings" when more than one value is found for the key.

For this, you can simply use

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(list)
for line in inmap:
    k, v = (x.strip() for x in line.split('\t'))
    data[k].append(v)
```

This works because a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of type `list` will automatically create a key together with an empty list as its value when you try to reference a key that doesn't yet exist. Otherwise, it behaves just like a normal dictionary.

Result:

```
>>> data
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'23301': ['Q8NDI1', 'A8K930'], 
'64343': ['H7BXU6', 'Q9H6S1', 'C9JB40'], '266743': ['Q8IUM7']})
```

Comment: Wooah, so simple! Guess I was just making it hard on myself. Worked like a charm, thanks a lot!